# How to create a CSS box link without using display: block

Tags: html, css

I made a navigation bar, however, I used the display: tag in the CSS so I cannot use it as block to create a box style link. Is there any other ways around this? My current code is:

CSS:

```
    ul.nav{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  border-width:1px 0;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;
  width: 100%;
  display: table; 
table-layout: fixed;
}
/* this styles each link when the mouse is NOT hovered over */
li.nav{
  display:block; text-align: center; 

}
/* Leave this alone fgt */
li.nav{
  display:block;
  padding:10px;
  display: table-cell; text-align: center; 
}
/* style of the hovered link. Change background colour rom black to whatever.  */
li.nav:hover {
    background-color: #0099FF;
    display:block; text-align: center; 
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
<li class="nav"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li class="nav"><a href="#news">News</a></li>
<li class="nav"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
<li class="nav"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: li a{
  display:block;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following classes:

```
li a {
    display:block;

    width:100%;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #0099FF;
}
```

and remove the property

```
padding:10px;
```

from the `li.nav` class.

This will give you what you want.

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/fTMQG/

Hope this helps!!!